# Why isn't $U = ${$f(x) | f(x) \in P_3, f(2) = 1$} a subspace of $P_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Problem:  Is the following a subspace of $P_3?$
$U = ${$f(x) | f(x) \in P_3, f(2) = 1$}
Where $P_3$ is the set of all polynomials of degree $\le$ 3

Why is U not a subspace of P_3? I'm guessing that it is related to $f(2) = 1$ and the but I do not know exactly how to explain it.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: The set of all polynomials of degree $\le$ 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f(2) = 1$ and $g(2) = 1$, is $(f+g)(2) = 1$?

Comment: So then the set is not closed under addition and is therefore not a subspace?

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Because if $f(2)=1$, $g(2)=1$, $(f+g)(2)\neq 1$, for instance. It is likewise not compatible with scalar multiplication.

It is an *affine* subspace, directed by the *vector* subspace  $\;Z(2)=\{f\in P_3\mid f(2)=0\}$, i.e. if $f(2)=g(2)=1$, then $f-g\in Z(2)$.